# Long press gesture on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

there.

I added a long press gesture to the self.view, but sadly, this gesture fires more than once every time it is recognized. Code is listed. every time gesture is recognized, 2 actionsheets showed up.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
         longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
         [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
      }


    -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
     {
        UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Hello",nil];
        [action showInView:self.view];
     }
```

Comment: What is `self.view`? Are you sure that this is the `UIWebView`?

Comment: sorry, my bad. i have updated the post content now. and i figured out that i should only concern the begin state:if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {}

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think i just should be only concern the begin state of the gesture in the action method:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Hello",nil];
      [action showInView:self.view];
   }
}
```

Comment: For the long press, the only state of interest is Began.